# Where is the correct place to parse (csv) data

Tags: csv, view, typo3

My typo3 plugin has to show data in it's view which is seperated by ";" 
[image] 
Now i have to convert/parse this data before showing it so it looks more like this:
[image]
I'm not sure where the right place for this functionality is... (the view itself or the controller etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put the parsing in the controller, and pass the resulting array to the view.

Parsing CSV and handling all the errors within the view is .. not sane.

Comment: so using javascript to sperate entrys and adding the tags is not an option at all?

Comment: You're a programmer, you can do anything in your code. The question is what's better, and using PHP's `fgetcsv()` seems to be the more sensible  compared to using Javascript to parse the csv.